# Retrieve the list of installed applications of a remote Windows system

Tags: remote-access

Are there any software that I can list down the list of installed application of a remote Windows system?

The remote Windows system can be a Windows 7 or Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 system or Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2012.

The local Windows system can be a Windows XP or Windows Vista or Windows 7 system.

Basically, the software will be installed on the local Windows system. It will scan the network for other remote Windows system and report to the local Windows system of the list of installed applications installed.

The software just need to be installed on the local Windows system. It does not need to be installed on the individual remote Windows system.

Some configuration such as open the ports of the remote Windows system is fine with me.

The network may not be a Active Directory network.